An integral inequality with lipschitz function

Suppose that $m=\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x),K=\int_a^b\frac{dx}{f(x)}$,
$f(x)>0$ and it satisfies $\forall x,y\in[a,b],|f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|$.
Prove that $\int_a^bf(x)dx\le \frac{e^{2LK}-1}{2L}m^2$.

I've tried use Sitaru-Schweitzer inequality, which is $K\int_b^af(x)\le \frac{(M+m)^2}{4Mm}(b-a)^2$, but it doesn't work when $M/m$ is large.
I guess that if I replace $e^{2LK}-1$ with $2LK+2L^2K^2$ (Taylor's formula), this inequality will also hold. But I haven't proved it yet.
Hope that someone can help me.

Did you try Jensen's inequality? Notice that 1/x is convex.

@Yao, but it's 1/f(x) not 1/x.

Remark. We use Maple to simplify the expressions.
Proof.
Let $c\in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) = m$.
From $|f(x) - f(c)| \le L|x - c|$, we have
$$f(x) \le m + L|x - c|. \tag{1}$$
Using (1), we have
$$\int_a^b f(x)\, \mathrm{d} x
\le \int_a^c (m + L(c-x)) \,\mathrm{d} x
+ \int_c^b (m + L(x - c))\,\mathrm{d} x. \tag{2}$$
Using (1), we have
\begin{align*}
 K &= \int_a^c \frac{1}{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d} x
 + \int_c^b \frac{1}{f(x)}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \int_a^c \frac{1}{m + L(c - x)}\,\mathrm{d} x
 + \int_c^b \frac{1}{m + L(x - c)}\,\mathrm{d} x, \tag{3}
\end{align*}
and thus
$$\mathrm{e}^{2LK} \ge \frac{(Lb - Lc + m)^2(Lc - La + m)^2}{m^4}. \tag{4}$$
From (2) and (4), it suffices to prove that
$$\int_a^c (m + L(c-x)) \,\mathrm{d} x
+ \int_c^b (m + L(x - c))\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \frac{\frac{(Lb - Lc + m)^2(Lc - La + m)^2}{m^4} - 1}{2L}m^2$$
or
$$\frac{L(b - c)(c - a)(Lb - Lc + 2m)(Lc - La + 2m)}{2m^2} \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.
We are done.
